# Does kubectl drain remove pod first or create pod first

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Kubernetes version 1.12.3. Does kubectl drain remove pod first or create pod first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use kubectl drain to safely evict all of your pods from a node before you perform maintenance on the node (e.g. kernel upgrade, hardware maintenance, etc.)

When kubectl drain return successfuly it means it has removed all the pods successfully from that node and it is safe to bring that node down(physically shut off, or start maintainence)

Now if you turn on the machine and want to schedule pods again on that node you need to run:

```
kubectl uncordon <node name>
```

So, `kubectl drain` removes pods from the node and don't schedule any pods on that until you uncordon that node

Comment: Use the kubectl drain command to drop the node without interrupting the service?

Comment: If you have replicas of pods running on other node, then yes you can drain the node without interrupting the service.

Comment: So if there is only one copy of pod and it is on the expelled node, there will be an interrupt?

Comment: Yes for some time, until that pod is recreated on other available node

Comment: Can kubectl drain create a new pod first before terminating an old one?

Comment: No, kubectl drain just removes the pod then its responsibility of kubernetes controller manager to spawn another pod to make available pod = expected pod. Hence it will always be after that pod is terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

kubectl drain will ignore certain system pods on the node that cannot be killed.
The given node will be marked unscheduled to prevent new pods from arriving.

When you are ready to put the node back into service, use kubectl uncordon, which will make the node schedulable again.

For for details use command: 
kubectl drain --help

With this I hope you will get information which you are looking.